# Update private chain from homestead to byzantium

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain, upgrading

I need to update my the version of my chain from homestead to Byzantium. Who can tell me how to do it? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to modify `params\config.go` function :

```
// IsByzantium returns whether num is either equal to the Byzantium fork block or greater.
func (c *ChainConfig) IsByzantium(num *big.Int) bool {
    return isForked(c.ByzantiumBlock, num)
}
```

Can return `true` to allow `Byzantium` rules.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Yes I can only modify the code in my local client, but I can make sure all of the client update to the code by themselves.